# How to add an onComplete event to the Xpages extLib valuePicker control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an extensionLibrary valuePicker control on my XPage and I'd like to run some search code after user selection. How can I achive this. Any onComplete events? I'd like to omit an "onchange" event at the target field (user may change it manually and then I'd like to start search on Enter or Search Button click)

```
        <xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker1"
            for="TargetField" pickerText="Select"
            dialogTitle="Select">
            <xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:simpleValuePicker labelSeparator="|">
                    <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:getMyValues()}]]></xe:this.valueList>
                </xe:simpleValuePicker>
            </xe:this.dataProvider>
        </xe:valuePicker>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code, it looks like the Value Picker calls XSP.selectValue() passing in the dojoType of the dialog to show, by default `extlib.dijit.PickerList`. It's triggering an AJAX request to retrieve the values, but opening and closing the dialog is done via CSJS only. So there's no onComplete event like partial refresh. And there's no current hook to add CSJS to run when closing. But it would be possible to extend that JavaScript file and trigger that instead. I'm not sure in your use case what corresponding code you would then need for your Edit Box control.

My preferred method is to use the Dojo List Text Box to hold the selected values (rather than an Edit Box or other manually editable component), then use an onChange event on that target field. Personally I feel it gives a better user experience, discourages manual typing and avoids needing to validate the Edit Box for user input.